# Ionic App breaks after updating to angular 8 -> Can't resolve all parameters for setupPlatform: (?, ...)

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

Steps to reproduce:
1. Build ionic app project with the following dependencies
2. Run ionic serve

- I already consulted the following post, which did not help me: [Error: Can't resolve all parameters for setupPlatform: (?, [object Object], [object Object])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858934/error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-setupplatform-object-object-obj)
- The problem is because of the deprecation of DOCUMENT which is used as the first parameter in initPlatform()
- Error occurs also on android and iOS
- Error could be related because project base was originally an ionic 3 project, which was updated

Error Message:

```
compiler.js:2420 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for setupPlatform: (?, [object Object], [object Object]).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2420)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:21576)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getFactoryMetadata (compiler.js:21475)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:21708)
    at compiler.js:21638
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:21598)
    at compiler.js:21220
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:21211)
```

My dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.7",
    "@ionic-native/app-rate": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.15.1",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/wheel-selector": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.1.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "^3.1.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.52",
    "@types/cordova": "^0.0.34",
    "@types/node": "^12.6.8",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.0.10",
    "aws-appsync": "^3.0.3",
    "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": "^10.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-apprate": "^1.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support": "1.6.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^6.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.11.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-purchase": "git+https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase.git#v9",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.7",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-wheel-selector-plugin": "^1.1.7",
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "graphql": "^0.11",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.3",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9",
    "ionic-tooltips": "^3.1.0",
    "ionicons": "^4.6.3",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "ngx-ionic-image-viewer": "^0.7.0",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "turndown": "^6.0.0",
    "video.js": "^7.5.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.9",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "browserslist": "^4.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.7",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^8.2.7",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^8.2.7",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.2.7",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^6.0.2",
    "promise.prototype.finally": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.0.2",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "^5.11.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  },
```

Ionic Info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 6.7.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.10
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 18 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.14.0
   native-run  : 1.0.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/matthias/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.10.0
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v14.0.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/14.0.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.4
   OS                : macOS Catalina
   Xcode             : Xcode 11.4.1 Build version 11E503a
```

Comment: I solved it temporarily using this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56829879/13466562

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading Cordova to a stable version- 8.1.2. Some of the functionality breaks in Cordova 9.0.0. 
npm i cordova@8.1.2