# When i upgrade from angular 7 to 8 i get this error:

Tags: angular, webpack, module

When I upgrade from angular 7 to 8 I get this error:

> ERROR in
>   ./src/app/features/fleet-status/fleet-status.module.ngfactory.js
>   144:5856-5868 "export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i39') was not found in
>   '@angular/platform-browser' ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
>   251:11369-11381 "export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i76') was not found
>   in '@angular/platform-browser'

I was looking in my project when that import I called but I didn't find it. Some idea?

Comment: Please check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826692/export-document-was-not-found-in-angular-platform-browser

Comment: This is for ionic maybe. i dont have that folder in my node_modules :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you import DOCUMENT in your fleet-status component?

Comment: Its not a problem in project files :(

Comment: please check your app module and components or any other modules. i think you have import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser'; if you have this line please replace with import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common';