# Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in Angular 11 while ng serve

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, angular, angular11

1. I have upgraded my Angular version from 5.2 to 11.2
2. And after upgrading Angular & all library when i start server **(ng serve)** getting **Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory**
3. It also generates 1 file which has information, but i didn't get

> **can you please help me out of this.**

[image]

[image]

1. Angular version & details
   [image]

[image]

Comment: it depends on your PC memory size, you can add this to your package.json file :
`{ ...
"start": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
..}`

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez i have tried with that but getting multiple error **"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i28') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'**

Comment: When updating, it is usually better to update the versions, one by one...

Comment: @StPaulis yes, i have upgrade all library one by one & resolve all issues, but when i am trying to compile it gives **javascript heap out of memory** error

Comment: I ment, that you should first update to Angular 6, then Angular 7, then 8...

Comment: @StPaulis yes, i do same from **https://update.angular.io/** this website, but when i tried with Angular 8 & upgrade all libraries then i get above all errors,

Comment: Do you have the project in a public repository?

Comment: @OwenKelvin no, it's not public, but i will provide some information, if you want

Comment: @Chaudhary Looks like you have 2 problems: a memory error that you have resolved by adding `--max_old_space_size` and a lot of errors caused by `export 'DOCUMENT'`

Answer (score 10):

Set an environment variable:

```
SET NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8048
```

Comment: after set this i am getting some **DOCUMENT** error, which i have added screenshot at last, & also i moved DOCUMENT to @angular/common, but still i am getting error

Answer (score 8):

I found this error comes from the generation of source maps. Disabling source maps will make the error go away.

Since most need source maps, using the solution for increase memory in npm scripts instead of disabling source maps, solves it.

example:

```json
scripts: {
  "build": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build",
  "serve": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can allocate more memory for your build/start task in order to compile:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build
```

And, according to an answer to this question: ["export 'DOCUMENT' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826692/export-document-was-not-found-in-angular-platform-browser), `DOCUMENT` has been moved to `@angular/common`. So you also have to change your imports for your code to compile.

Comment: when i set **node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve**, i start my server but get compile error, thats come from .ngFctory file, & i already import DOCUMENT from @angular/common

Comment: i added screenshot of *DOCUMENT* error, please review.

Answer (score 2):

After tried all solutions above and in other threads, i realized i installed 32 bit node js instead of 64bit (angular 16 but the problem is not angular version related)

Answer (score 1):

GIT BASH:
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8048 && ng build

CMD
SET NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8048 && ng build

Answer (score 1):

As of Node.js v8.0 shipped August 2017, you can use the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable to set the max_old_space_size globally

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
```

@see https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit

Answer (score 0):

The problem node.js process consuming more memory over time , so increased the memory allocation for the Node.js process. which can be helpful for handling larger applications or projects with heavy memory usage.

> The command used for :
> **"node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve"**