# 'outputHashing' option is disabled when using the dev-server

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

I cloned a repository from git and executed `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` after that I did `ng serve` and it says outputHasing is disabled. But in 'angular.json' file I'm having 'outputhashing' = all
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtUlH.png)

how to solve this and what does the error mean?

Comment: The error message "outputHashing" option is disabled when using the dev-server means that the output hashing feature is not enabled for the development server. This is because the development server is designed for rapid development and reloading of code changes, and output hashing can slow down this process.
However, for development, the performance benefits of output hashing are not as significant, and the overhead of generating the hash values can actually slow down the development process. Therefore, output hashing is disabled by default for the development server.

Comment: If you need to use output hashing for development, you can do so by adding the following flag to the ng serve command:

`ng serve --output-hashing=all`

Comment: This is just a warning that something about your configuration is wrong, but Angular just ignores it and proceeds with starting the dev server. The actual problem is below: "FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory". There are a lot of questions in that regard, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67748747/5470544. Do you want to get rid of the warning (which will not make the dev server work), or fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a warning during the compilation of my Angular application and discovered that it was caused by the 'outputHashing' configuration in the 'angular.json' file. In the development build configuration, removing the 'outputHashing=all' setting resolved the warning for me. After making this change, the warning no longer appeared during compilation.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzTRE.png)